# Changed minted text color - no language (text option)

Tags: minted

I wanted to enclose a bit of text/minimal HTML code in a minted text box. The HTML (a couple `<br>` and `<a href='link'>` doesn't matter to me, so I opted to use the text option for language in minted. However, I want to emphasize a few things in red text that are not HTML elements. For example:

```
Go to this link <a href="domain.com/upload/[UPLOAD_ID]"> to find your upload.
```

I would like the `[UPLOAD_ID]` to be in red. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minted documentation has a way to highlight text, as shown here:

[image]

As far as I understand, it is achieved by escaping the minted environment and executing the `\colorbox`  command. It is possible to use the `\textcolor` command, as shown by user187803 instead of `\colorbox`  to make it work with  minted.

Example:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
def f(x):
   y = x|\textcolor{red}{**}|2
   return y
\end{minted}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Applying it to your example, the underscore in `[UPLOAD_ID]` needs to be escaped with a backslash `[UPLOAD\_ID]`. This is necessary because the underscore is normally used to index a character. But in this case the underscore should be printed as an underscore and not interpreted to make an index out of `ID`. If we do not use the backslash here, it will result in an error.

Provided Example:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{text}
    Go to this link <a href="domain.com/upload/|\textcolor{red}{[UPLOAD\_ID]}|"> to find your upload
\end{minted}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on using `minted`, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
Go to this link <a href="domain.com/upload/\textcolor{red}{[UPLOAD_ID]}"> to find your upload.
\end{Verbatim}

\fvset{commandchars=\\\{\}}
Go to this link \Verb|<a href="domain.com/upload/\textcolor{red}{[UPLOAD_ID]}">| to find your upload.

\end{document}
```

[image]